# Tell pgfplots to put tick labels between tick marks

Tags: pgfplots, labels, ticks

Is it possible to tell `pgfplots` to put tick labels *between* the tick marks instead of *at* the tick marks?

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \begin{axis}[
            width=5in,
            height=3in,
            axis lines=middle,
            scaled ticks=false,
            xtick=\empty,
            xmin=0,
            xmax=3,
            extra x ticks={0,1,2,3},
            extra x tick labels={low,high,med},
        ]

        \addplot [mark=*,draw] coordinates {(0.5,2) (1.5,4) (2.5,3)};

        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**Result:**

[image]

I can do it manually by adding

```
xticklabel style = {xshift=1.9cm,align=center},
```

[image]

but this seems unsatisfying, unreliable, and requires too much trial and error.

Comment: Why not use `extra x ticks={0.5,1.5,2.5},`?

Comment: Because then the tick *marks* will appear at 0.5, 1.5, 2.5, which I don't want -- I want the marks at the integers.

Comment: The image is meant to suggest "in between 0 and 1, things are *low*; in between 1 and 2, things are *high*; in between 2 and 3, things are *medium*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \begin{axis}[
            width=5in,
            height=3in,
            axis lines=middle,
            scaled ticks=false,
            xtick=\empty,
            xmin=0,
            xmax=3,
            xtick={0,1,2,3},
            xticklabel=\empty,
            extra x ticks={0.5,1.5,2.5},
            extra x tick labels={low,high,med},
            extra x tick style={major tick length=0pt}
        ]

        \addplot [mark=*,draw] coordinates {(0.5,2) (1.5,4) (2.5,3)};

        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, but I don't want the tick *marks* at the labels -- I want them at the integers (in this MWE).

Comment: @LarrySnyder610 Now there are no more ticks at the extra positions.

Comment: OK, that works. It's still a little clunky IMO because there's a lot of manual handling (i.e., I'm still basically doing the x-shifting manually). In my actual figure, there are a lot more intervals on the x-axis, so it's a bit tedious, but workable. I was hoping there was just an option like `labels between ticks`. Anyway, I'll keep my eye out for a more automated solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`x tick label as interval` is just what you want, but the problem is with `axis lines=middle` the tick position 0 is ignored by default and no tick is generated, so there are only two tick intervals instead of three, and so the first label ("low") goes missing.

My solution is to use `extra x ticks` to supply the missing interval and label but keep the extra ticks from showing with the help of `style`.

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \begin{axis}[
            width=5in,
            height=3in,
            axis lines=middle,
            scaled ticks=false,
            xmin=0,
            xmax=3,
            x tick label as interval,
            xtick={1,2,3},
            xticklabels={high,med},
            % first label would be missing w/o the lines below
            extra x ticks={0.1, 0.9},
            extra x tick labels={low},
            extra x tick style={
                tick style={draw=none}
            },
        ]

        \addplot [mark=*,draw] coordinates {(0.5,2) (1.5,4) (2.5,3)};

        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]