# pgfplots: use dimensions instead of ticks

Tags: pgfplots, dimensions, ticks

I need to build a graphic in pgfplots with symbolic distances between the keypoints, as shown in the figure below. I know how to use symbolic coords, but if I was to represent the x coordinates as normally, the ticks would be 't1', 't1+t2', 't1+t2+t3', and so on... So I thought it would be better if I represented the x axis using dimensions, and set the ticks as dimension marks, just like I tried to illustrate in the figure. (The figure was edited in Paint, so sorry about the quality :P)

I wonder if there's any built-in way to perform this, or else any work-around. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: See e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/491482).

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat thank you! :)